# How can I use expressjs staticfiles after deploying backend app on Railway?

Tags: javascript, express, backend, static-files, railway

In the code images add to the /static folder, but where can I get the elements from this folder with Railway?

```js
const models = require("./models");
const router = require("./routes");
const errorHandler = require("./middleware/errorHandlingMiddleware");

const cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const path = require("path");
require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "static")));
app.use(fileUpload({}));
app.use("/api", router);

// errors
app.use(errorHandler);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const startServer = async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.authenticate();
    await sequelize.sync();
    app.listen(PORT, "0.0.0.0", () => {
      console.log("http://localhost:" + PORT);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

startServer();
```

It is my index.js file where all staticfiles is stored in the /static folder. I just want to know how to get static files in Railway.

I didn't find this information anywhere.I would be glad if you help me find the answer to my unusual question.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out what the URL should be for images in the static folder?  Can you provide some code or configuration examples that shows the setup and the problem?  Can you provide a link to the code that says you need to put things in the static folder?

Comment: I asked the question more correctly.